# How to identify whether a website has a modal popup displayed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

A growing number of sites are using modal popups. Sometimes the use is arguably justified, but more frequently I see bad UX like a popup asking for my email address before I've even had a chance to skim the article that brought me to their site in the first place. Needless to say, I'm making a browser extension to get rid of these.

The approach that similar extensions have used seems to be letting the user identify whether the site has an unwanted modal popup and removing the most likely candidate (e.g. highest z-index) on a button press. If nothing better comes along this design is fine enough, but I would like to be able to obviate the need for a button press and simply **detect whether a site is displaying a modal popup**.

#### Current Approaches

- **Search for an obnoxious z-index**. Ofttimes these popups are coded with z-indices of 1000+ to ensure that they appear on top no matter what other design decisions are made. While a nice heuristic, this is unreliable.
- **Examine the overflow attribute** on html and body. Many times sites will disable scrolling when using their popups, so if the site can't be scrolled it's a strong indication that one exists. I'm re-enabling scrolling anyway, so this isn't really any extra work.
- **Store a history** of sites the user decides to blacklist. If no 100% foolproof method exists, this should still be an improvement over requiring a button press every time.

TLDR; Is there a way to examine an HTML element (and/or any corresponding CSS, JS, etc...) and determine whether it is or is not a modal popup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these approaches are enough, for the user experience If I am a user I want to know what are you doing, maybe you can add two modes to control by users:**Confirm** and **Recovery** and you can analyze it which sites user does not remove `modal`.

- Confirm: use Dom inspector let the user know which DOM will be removed and select 'Yes' or 'No' to execute.
- Recovery: maybe sometimes removed modal it is not user expected. You can save the site URL to log and analyze it.